# How do I use the median of 3 rules to find the pivot point?

Tags: data-structures

Suppose I have a list of numbers like this:

```
2 23 19 3 5 28 31 67 44 35 6 33 19 45
```

How do I find the pivot point using the median of 3 method?

I thought it involves adding the first and last numbers,and then dividing it by 2, but apparently that's wrong.

Comment: So your actual question is "what is a median", right? You should use a better title

Comment: @harold When you phrase it like that, you make it sound like median of 3 is really just the median number. Is it?

Comment: Well yes, but of 3 numbers, to make it easier to compute (otherwise how would you even find it, sort the array? oh..) The first/last/middle part is just which items you'd typically pick to compute the median of, but the median is then just a regular old median

Comment: So in this case, the pivot would be 31?